# My app crashes and hangs after 30 seconds

Tags: android, android-log, android-monitor

I am getting this Log warnings

```
09-29 17:05:27.539 16093-19955/com.popcornstay.popcornstay W/art: Long 

monitor contention with owner Timer-83 (19829) at boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long)(MessageQueue.java:547) waiters=143 in boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long) for 8.702s
09-29 17:05:27.539 16093-16277/com.popcornstay.popcornstay W/art: Long monitor contention with owner Timer-83 (19829) at boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long)(MessageQueue.java:547) waiters=143 in boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long) for 8.702s
09-29 17:05:27.539 16093-19915/com.popcornstay.popcornstay W/art: Long monitor contention with owner Timer-83 (19829) at boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long)(MessageQueue.java:547) waiters=143 in boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long) for 8.668s
09-29 17:05:27.539 16093-16553/com.popcornstay.popcornstay W/art: Long monitor contention with owner Timer-83 (19829) at boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long)(MessageQueue.java:547) waiters=143 in boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long) for 8.700s
09-29 17:05:27.539 16093-16465/com.popcornstay.popcornstay W/art: Long monitor contention with owner Timer-83 (19829) at boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long)(MessageQueue.java:547) waiters=143 in boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long) for 8.703s
09-29 17:05:27.539 16093-20640/com.popcornstay.popcornstay W/art: Long monitor contention with owner Timer-83 (19829) at boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long)(MessageQueue.java:547) waiters=143 in boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long) for 8.668s
09-29 17:05:27.539 16093-22796/com.popcornstay.popcornstay W/art: Long monitor contention with owner Timer-121 (20431) at boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long)(MessageQueue.java:547) waiters=143 in boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long) for 8.600s
09-29 17:05:27.539 16093-19829/com.popcornstay.popcornstay W/art: Long monitor contention with owner main (16093) at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next()(MessageQueue.java:331) waiters=143 in boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long) for 8.601s
09-29 17:05:27.539 16093-17260/com.popcornstay.popcornstay W/art: Long monitor contention with owner Timer-83 (19829) at boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long)(MessageQueue.java:547) waiters=143 in boolean android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(android.os.Message, long) for 8.668s
```

Please help me out of this.

Because of this my app is not working and hang after 30 seconds.

Suggest any solution for this.

This cause to hang and ANR after that.

Comment: share some code please

Comment: share your code

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's cause a one thread is not responds too much time and blocks other threads. App might do too much tasks in the one thread. Try to find this thread and unload it. Start from it. If nothing - write me here and we can go to the pm.

Comment: I have only the Volley library calls, I did remove all volley requests. Still, it gets hang after few moments. Especially it was working very fine a month back. Don't know what's wrong with this now.

Comment: I have the same issue however I do not know how to unload it. You may see my similar question in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378433/long-monitor-contention-with-owner-warning