# "Long monitor contention with owner" warning

Tags: android, multithreading, google-play-services, android-anr-dialog, android-handlerthread

I get this **warning message** and since I see this message I also started to see the **Google Play Services isnt responding** popup and it **closes my application** after some time. I have review similar questions but could not find out the reason.

Following is a sample of my handler thread usage. I do not know what to do to avoid this problem.

```
@Override
public void find(Func1<RealmQuery<Artist>, RealmQuery<Artist>> query,
                 Action1<Result<List<Artist>>> onResult) {
    if (query != null) {


        handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThreadArtist");
        handlerThread.start();
        looper = handlerThread.getLooper();

        Handler handler = new Handler(looper);

        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Timber.log(Log.DEBUG, "ARTISTDAOIMPL", "find Thread.currentThread().getName() " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                mDatabase.findRealmObject(Artist.class, query,
                        result -> onResult.call(
                                Result.getData(Arrays.asList(result.data.toArray(new Artist[]{})))
                        ), err -> onResult.call(Result.getError(err))
                );
            }
        });

    }


12-17 15:56:44.631  2944  2977 W art     : Long monitor contention with owner Answers Events Handler1 (2983) at java.lang.Object java.lang.Throwable.nativeFillInStackTrace!()(Throwable.java:-2) waiters=0 in io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfo io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.IdManager.getAdvertisingInfo() for 274ms
```

I use **fabric** to get the **crash reports.** Not sure if it is related with that or not.
This part is from the `traces.txt` file that shows info about **Answers Events Handler1** I thought that would be helpful.

```
"Answers Events Handler1" prio=5 tid=21 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12ca50d0 self=0x9fe5b200
  | sysTid=32081 nice=10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x9307f920
  | state=S schedstat=( 53200042 321330653 137 ) utm=2 stm=3 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x92f7d000-0x92f7f000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x0b62dbce> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
  - locked <0x0b62dbce> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1084)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:75)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

This is the other one of the similar warning:

```
12-17 15:16:05.729 32041 32084 W art     : Long monitor contention with owner Queue (32074) at boolean android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int)(Binder.java:-2) waiters=1 in io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfo io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.IdManager.getAdvertisingInfo() for 267ms
```

This part is also from the `traces.txt` file about **"Queue"**:

```
"Queue" prio=10 tid=20 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c56280 self=0x9fe5ad00
  | sysTid=32077 nice=10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x93249920
  | state=S schedstat=( 2336754 827421 7 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x93147000-0x93149000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x061c78c9> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
  - locked <0x061c78c9> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
  at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.performOperation(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:197)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.get(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:236)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:65)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.take(DependencyPriorityBlockingQueue.java:46)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

First, it was showing **specific handler thread names** that I used in the application. Currently it does not show them but it prints these ones.

I need to learn that if it is a big issue and how to fix them.

Thanks.

Comment: This post is quite old but yes it can be a big issue. You've got some mutex locks that are waiting for a long time and it seems to be related to Fabric.  Try disabling Fabric and see if the issue still happens.

Comment: More info: https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/coots99/full_papers/liang/liang_html/node16.html